# overflow when using uint32_t

Tags: c, overflow, uint32-t

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* createMSG(uint8_t i,uint32_t port);

int strlen(char* tmp);
uint32_t user_port = 5000;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *msg;
    uint8_t i;
    i = 1;  
    msg = createMSG(i,user_port);
    printf("Port: %d",*(msg+2));
}

char* createMSG(uint8_t i,uint32_t port) {
    char *buff; 
    buff = (char*) malloc(6);
    uint8_t id;
    id = 2;
    memcpy(buff, &id, sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(buff+1, &i, sizeof(uint8_t));
    memcpy(buff+2, &port, sizeof(uint32_t));
    return buff;
}
```

The output is: "Port: -120". It seems there is some overflow. But uint32_t should be big enough for 5000. When using 22 instead of 5000, everything is ok.

Why?

Comment: Also `%d` is not the correct format for an `uint32_t`. First that would be a format for a signed value and not unsigned. Then you usually don't know if `unsigned` corresponds to a 32 bit type. The correct macro for the format is `PRIu32` something like `"Port: %" PRIu32 "\n"` (yes this is ugly). Also don't forget the `\n` at the end of a `printf` to be sure that you see the output.

Comment: Hi, i never heard about PRIu32. From now i will PRIu32, to prevent unexpected behavior. Till now %d did always his job. When sending msg with sendto(), i am getting a wrong value for *(msg+2) again, even if i use `(uint32_t*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
printf("Port: %d",*(msg+2));
```

prints the 'char' value at (msg+2) address, not the uint32_t !

Use

```
uint32_t PortFromProc = *(uint32_t*)(msg+2);
printf("Port: %d", PortFromProc);
```

To "fix" port numbers from recvfrom() function one must use the ntohl() function.

Comment: Hi, this works. But when sending msg with sendto() (UDP) and receiving it with recvfrom uint32_t PortFromProc = *(uint32_t*)(msg+2); has a wrong value again.

Comment: The port numbers in recvfrom() are in big-endian format (highest byte goes first). Use ntohs/ntohl functions for the value recieved from recvfrom().

Comment: Dp you mean sth like this `uint32_t PortFromProc = htonl(*(uint32_t*)(msg+2));` ?

Comment: Yes. However, many people here including me would recommend you to avoid using these crazy type-casts with pointers. Split the code to multiple lines. This will help you to avoid the problems like the one in your code.

Comment: I thought using ntohs/ntohl is only important for setting the port to sockaddr_in. When sending messages with sendto i have never used htonl. And when sending uint8_t with sendto, it works correctly, but why not with uint32_t? Sorry i forgot to say that i dont use recvfrom, but select().

Comment: There is a convention that all socket functions accept port numbers in Big-Endian format (higher byte first), which is the exact opposite of the Little-Endian format used on Intel-based machines. If you do the send/recv(or send/bind) pair of operations on two different machines, you just make the "double fault" of inverting bytes and thus it seems like it's working.

Answer (score 4):

Because `*(msg+2)` has type `char`. If you really want to do that, you should do

```
printf("Port: %d",*(uint32_t*)(msg+2));
```

As noted by *@R..*, msg+2 almost certainly does not meet the right alignment requirements for type uint32_t. If the code appears to work, it's an accident and not portable.

Comment: That's not valid code. `msg+2` almost certainly does not meet the right alignment requirements for type `uint32_t`; if the code appears to work, it's an accident and not portable.